# Why are iAds not popping up, my code, or them?

Tags: ios, iad

After signing the iAd contract, I was expecting to see live ads on my test device. But unlike before not even the test ads are showing up. This is the quote I am basing it on: "iAd App Network serves live ads if you signed the iAd App Network Agreement and integrated iAd Framework in your app before submitting the app binary for review." So is my implementation of iAds is wrong, or is it just another problem?

EDIT:

```
 #pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods
 -(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:1]
     [banner setAlpha:1]
     [UIView commitAnimations];
 }

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView*)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:1]
     [banner setAlpha:0]
     [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

`
also I have in the header that this class is the delegate, and in the storyboard i link an iAd banner view's delegate to this class. This code worked with the test ads, never got a warning or error

Comment: While testing no live ads appear.  It is not until you actually submit and the app gets approved will you see live ads.  And then you still have to wait about 3 days for them to appear.

Comment: So should I just trust that I have the implementation correct? Because I don't want the app rejected over this.

Comment: Post your code on how you deal with the iAds.  Like when there are none and such.  We can take a look to see.

Comment: Alright thanks I posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your banner has been added to the view correctly, and this code is definitely be called, you implementation looks fine.

Live Ads are not served to an app whilst it is in non-live development. You should see a banner filled with a default Apple ad about iAds and why you should use them.